# Running code if textfield has specific text

Tags: arrays, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to launch code when a textField has specific text. If the user inserts "John" in the textField, I want to launch `loadData1()` function and if the user inserts "Sara" in the textField I want to launch `loadData2()`. I did a lot of research on YouTube and Stack Overflow but I didn't find any way so I decided to use  an if statement but also it didn't work for me.

```swift
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class orderTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var order: UITableView!
    var db: Firestore!
    var firstName = [String]()
    var lastName = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        db = Firestore.firestore()

        let view1 = firstViewController()

        if view1.firstName.text == "John" {
            loadData1
        }


        if view1.firstName.text == "Sara" {
            loadData2()
        }

    }

}

func loadData1() {

    db.collection("lastname").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {

            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")

            }
            self.order.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

func loadData2() {

    db.collection("lastname").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {

            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")

            }
            self.order.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A little off-topic but wouldn’t it be better to use some other type of control for this like a picker or radio buttons or such with a finite number of options to choose from

Answer (score 0):

You should set the delegate of your textField to the current class (e.g. ViewController) in the initialization of your class (e.g. in your viewDidLoad), like this:

```
view1.firstName.delegate = self
```

And then, add this method to your ViewController which is the delegate of your textField:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    // check your text here and do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Hi Abbas , i tried your code but it doesn't work , but if you know about firebase , i have many collections in firestore and i want to give each user different collections do you know how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For checking text changes in a `UITextField` you can do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //...
    yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
}
@objc func textFieldDidChange(){
    print(yourTextField.text)
    // check for specific text here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        // check your text here and do whatever you need
    if yourTextField.text == "You text" {
    // Text did match
    } else {
    // Text Did not match
    }
    }
```